# SQL SELECT rows with max date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `message`

```
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   
`from_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
`to_user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,  
`request_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`text` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
```

And data inside:

```
1   4   1   3   Text1       01.05.2014 14:02
2   4   1   3   Text2       02.05.2014 14:02
3   4   1   3   Text3       03.05.2014 14:02
4   4   1   4   Text4       04.05.2014 14:02
5   4   1   4   Text5       05.05.2014 14:02
6   2   1   3   Text6       06.05.2014 14:02
7   2   1   3   Text7       07.05.2014 14:02
```

For example first line represents following:
User 4 sent message 'Text1' regarding request 3 on 01.05.2014 14:02 to User 1.

I want to get all latest messages to user 1 for different requests.
The result I am expecting to get is:

```
3   4   1   3   Text3       03.05.2014 14:02
5   4   1   4   Text5       05.05.2014 14:02
7   2   1   3   Text7       07.05.2014 14:02
```

I have already tried:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` `t` 
   WHERE `to_user_id`='1' AND 
   `date` = 
      (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM 
         (SELECT * FROM `message` `t3` 
            WHERE `t3`.`request_id`=`t`.`request_id`
         ) `t2` 
         WHERE `t2`.`from_user_id`=`t`.`from_user_id`
      );
```

But it returned error `#1054 - Unknown column 't.request_id' in 'where clause'`

Seems like alias `t` is not reachable from inside `WHERE` clause.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

The table consists of offer_id and request_id. Only one of them can be NULL. Thanks to @fancyPants' answer I found out correct solution

```
SELECT * FROM `message` `t` 
WHERE `to_user_id`='1' AND 
`date` = 
   (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `message` `t2` 
    WHERE `t2`.`from_user_id`=`t`.`from_user_id`
    AND (`t2`.`request_id`=`t`.`request_id` OR 
    `t2`.`offer_id`=`t`.`offer_id`)
   );
```

Comment: Proabably no one's ever asked this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you're overcomplicating things. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM `message` `t` 
WHERE `to_user_id`='1' AND 
`date` = 
   (SELECT MAX(`date`) FROM `message` `t2` 
    WHERE `t2`.`from_user_id`=`t`.`from_user_id`
    AND `t2`.`request_id`=`t`.`request_id`
   );
```

Other ways to do so are described here: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this solution just after posting the question. While asking I tried to make the question easy-to-understand. The message can be regarding no-request (request_id = NULL) so in this case I need to get NULL as well in the result. But I am not getting rows with request_id = NULL

Answer (score 0):

You are right, t probably doesn't get passed down that deep. I had this problem here and there, too, with another dbms.

As to re-writing the query: You would typically write a query to get the max dates and then join the message table with this:

```
select m.*
from
(
  select to_user_id, request_id, max(`date`) as `date`
  from message
  where to_user_id = 1
  group by to_user_id, request_id
) last_m
inner join message m 
  on m.to_user_id = last_m.to_user_id 
  and m.request_id = last_m.request_id 
  and m.date = last_m.date;
```

I used special quotes on *date* where it is used without a qualifier as it is a reserved word.

Comment: Thanks for response. The same problem I already wrote in @fancyPants answer. `m.request_id = last_m.request_id` does not work for NULL